# I want to create array of objects MyClass ob[20]; Error: statically allocated instance of Objective-C class

Tags: objective-c

I want to create array of objects MyClass ob[20]; Error: statically allocated instance of Objective-C class 'MyClass'

@interface MyClass : NSObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an array of object *pointers*.

```
MyClass *ob[20];
```

Alternatively, use a high-level collection like `NSArray`.